# Как переделать выпадающий список в выпадающие радиокнопки? По возможности с чекбоксами

Tags: html, css

```css
.btn {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.btn:hover, .dropdown:hover .btn {
    background-color: #0b7dda;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn" style="border-left:1px solid navy">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>Radiobutton 1</a>
    <a>Radiobutton 2</a>
    <a>Radiobutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может быть, начать с замены ссылок на [чекбоксы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)?

Comment: что значит "радиокнопки с чекбоксами"? чекбоксы и радиокнопки - это разные самостоятельные типы инпутов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-level {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-level:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.btn:hover, .dropdown:hover .btn {
  background-color: #0b7dda;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn" style="border-left:1px solid navy">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="dropdown-level">
      <input type="radio" id="radiobutton_1" name="group">
      <label for="radiobutton_1">Radiobutton 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-level">
      <input type="radio" id="radiobutton_2" name="group">
      <label for="radiobutton_2">Radiobutton 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-level">
      <input type="checkbox" id="radiobutton_3">
      <label for="radiobutton_3">Radiobutton 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```